# Page preload effect doesn't work on new jquery version

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page preload effect on my site which works perfectly on jquery 1.5.x, but it does not work on the latest 3.1.1

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

```css
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 9999;
  
background: url(../assets/img/spinner.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it ever worked. That's not what `load()` does.

Comment: @BenM, actually, it has worked, but now that function is removed (not sure about last jQ version that used it).

Comment: Whenever something stops working after a version change (especially two major versions), you should always look for what changed. jQuery always has [release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) for every major and minor version change, which would have told you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what `load()` does. [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a short-hand function to fetch data from a URL, not an event wrapper. You should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: But you should mention that the shorthand for load event has been removed from jq 3.x  [$.fn.load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)